# Как подсветить поля или текст, которые изменены пользователем?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css

Как можно подсветить поля или текст, где пользователь внес изменения?

Есть простая таблица в базе данных с полями:

```
id, name, text, img, states, city, status, active ...
```

Мне нужно, чтобы когда администратор проверяет данные, выделить цветом только те данные, которые были изменены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого данные надо не изменять, а сохранять во временное хранилище.
А для подсвечивания разницы использовать любой diff.

После одобрения модератором данные в основном хранилище обновлять, а во временном удалять. или тоже сохранять, если нужна история изменений.

Допустим данные хранятся в БД.
Получаем два масива. прходим в цикле по первому и сравниваем его элементы с такими же во втором.

```
foreach ($old as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value != $new[$key]) // не совпадают
    {
        // тут diff
    }
}
```

реализацию diff искать в гугле по волшебному запросу php diff

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласный, только не могу понять как сравнить данные